# Calculate optimal input of a neural network with theano, by using gradient descent w.r.t. inputs

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, theano

I have implemented and trained a neural network with Theano of k binary inputs (0,1), one hidden layer and one unit in the output layer. Once it has been trained I want to obtain inputs that maximizes the output (e.g. x which makes unit of output layer closest to 1). So far I haven't found an implementation of it, so I am trying the following approach:

1. Train network => obtain trained weights (theta1, theta2)
2. Define the neural network function with x as input and trained theta1, theta2 as fixed parameters. That is: f(x) = sigmoid( theta1*(sigmoid (theta2*x ))). This function takes x and with given trained weights (theta1, theta2) gives output between 0 and 1.
3. Apply gradient descent w.r.t. x on the neural network function f(x) and obtain x that maximizes f(x) with theta1 and theta2 given.

For these I have implemented the following code with a toy example (k = 2). Based on the tutorial on http://outlace.com/Beginner-Tutorial-Theano/ but changed vector y, so that there is only one combination of inputs that gives f(x) ~ 1 which is x = [0, 1].

Edit1: As suggested `optimizer` was set to `None` and bias unit was fixed to 1.
**Step 1:** Train neural network. This runs well and with out error.

```
import os
os.environ["THEANO_FLAGS"] = "optimizer=None"
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
import theano.tensor.nnet as nnet
import numpy as np

x = T.dvector()
y = T.dscalar()

def layer(x, w):
    b = np.array([1], dtype=theano.config.floatX)
    new_x = T.concatenate([x, b])
    m = T.dot(w.T, new_x) #theta1: 3x3 * x: 3x1 = 3x1 ;;; theta2: 1x4 * 4x1
    h = nnet.sigmoid(m)
    return h

def grad_desc(cost, theta):
    alpha = 0.1 #learning rate
    return theta - (alpha * T.grad(cost, wrt=theta))

in_units = 2
hid_units = 3
out_units = 1

theta1 = theano.shared(np.array(np.random.rand(in_units + 1, hid_units), dtype=theano.config.floatX)) # randomly initialize
theta2 = theano.shared(np.array(np.random.rand(hid_units + 1, out_units), dtype=theano.config.floatX))

hid1 = layer(x, theta1) #hidden layer

out1 = T.sum(layer(hid1, theta2)) #output layer
fc = (out1 - y)**2 #cost expression

cost = theano.function(inputs=[x, y], outputs=fc, updates=[
        (theta1, grad_desc(fc, theta1)),
        (theta2, grad_desc(fc, theta2))])
run_forward = theano.function(inputs=[x], outputs=out1)

inputs = np.array([[0,1],[1,0],[1,1],[0,0]]).reshape(4,2) #training data X
exp_y = np.array([1, 0, 0, 0]) #training data Y
cur_cost = 0
for i in range(5000):
    for k in range(len(inputs)):
        cur_cost = cost(inputs[k], exp_y[k]) #call our Theano-compiled cost function, it will auto update weights

print(run_forward([0,1]))
```

Output of run forward for [0,1] is: 0.968905860574. 
We can also get values of weights with `theta1.get_value()` and `theta2.get_value()`

**Step 2:** Define neural network function f(x). Trained weights (theta1, theta2) are constant parameters of this function.

Things get a little trickier here because of the bias unit, which is part of he vector of inputs x. To do this I concatenate b and x. But the code now runs well.

```
b = np.array([[1]], dtype=theano.config.floatX)
#b_sh = theano.shared(np.array([[1]], dtype=theano.config.floatX))
rand_init = np.random.rand(in_units, 1)
rand_init[0] = 1
x_sh = theano.shared(np.array(rand_init, dtype=theano.config.floatX))
th1 = T.dmatrix()
th2 = T.dmatrix()

nn_hid = T.nnet.sigmoid( T.dot(th1, T.concatenate([x_sh, b])) )
nn_predict = T.sum( T.nnet.sigmoid( T.dot(th2, T.concatenate([nn_hid, b]))))
```

**Step 3:**
Problem is now in gradient descent as is not limited to values between 0 and 1.
    fc2 = (nn_predict - 1)**2

```
cost3 = theano.function(inputs=[th1, th2], outputs=fc2, updates=[
        (x_sh, grad_desc(fc2, x_sh))])
run_forward = theano.function(inputs=[th1, th2], outputs=nn_predict)

cur_cost = 0
for i in range(10000):

cur_cost = cost3(theta1.get_value().T, theta2.get_value().T) #call our Theano-compiled cost function, it will auto update weights
if i % 500 == 0: #only print the cost every 500 epochs/iterations (to save space)
    print('Cost: %s' % (cur_cost,))
    print x_sh.get_value()
```

The last iteration prints:
    Cost: 0.000220317356533
    [[-0.11492753]
     [ 1.99729555]]

Furthermore input 1 keeps becoming more negative and input 2 increases, while the optimal solution is [0, 1]. How can this be fixed?

Comment: try doing what the error message tells you to do. Rerun with optimizer=None and it will tell you which multiplication is the problem.

Comment: Did and added the result in question. Is it in T.dot(th2, nn_hid)? is nn_hid not well defined?

Comment: Define the neural network function (f = sigmoid( theta1*sigmoid (theta2*x + b) + b)) which takes value theta1 and theta2 and returns x (vector of k binary inputs).

I did not get this. As far as I know, such problems are solved using backpropagation w.r.t inputs. In means, you take your trained network, perform a normal forward pass, and then propagate error back, but w.r.t hidden and input values, not weights.

Comment: Yes, so to train the network you use backpropagation w.r.t. inputs and obtain the weights (theta1 and theta2). But now I want to obtain the optimal input to maximize the output of the trained neural network. So I want a function that takes as parameters the trained weights (theta1, theta2) and x as input. Then I want to find x such that, with the parameters theta1, theta2 given, maximizes the output. In this example, I want the answer I want to get is: x= [0, 1] will max f(x; theta1, theta2).

Answer (score 1):

You are adding b=[1] via broadcasting rules as opposed to concatenating it. Also, once you concatenate it, your x_sh has one dimension to many which is why the error occurs at nn_predict and not nn_hid

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I see your point but when I try to concatenate b with:  'T.concatenate([x_sh, b])' I get error:
 'TypeError: Join() can only join tensors with the same number of dimensions.' 
I also tried T.concatenate([x_sh.T, b]) but got same error.

Comment: that's just a matter of making them have the same shape. Try [[1]].

Comment: [[1]] solves that error, but now I get:
'TypeError: ('update target must be a SharedVariable', Join.0)'
I tried doing 'b_sh = theano.shared(np.array([[1]], dtype=theano.config.floatX))' 
and then concatenating (x_sh = T.concatenate([x_sh, b_sh])), but get same error

Comment: I tried working it around by making the x_sh out of a numpy array that already had b. That is:
rand_init = np.random.rand(in_units + 1, 1) ;   rand_init[0] = 1
;   x_sh = theano.shared(np.array(rand_init, dtype=theano.config.floatX))". But get same error than in post, again in nn_predict and with: Inputs shapes: [(4, 1), (3, 1)]
Inputs strides: [(8, 8), (8, 8)]

Comment: You get that problem because of nn_hid, not because of x_sh. But that's not a valid workaround anyway since you'll learn the term that should be constant 1

Comment: I think this is better: nn_hid1 = T.nnet.sigmoid( T.dot(th1[1:], x_sh) ) ; 
nn_hid2 = T.nnet.sigmoid( T.dot(th1[0], b) ) ; 
nn_predict1 = T.sum( T.nnet.sigmoid( T.dot(th2[1:], nn_hid1) ) ) ; 
nn_predict2 = T.sum( T.nnet.sigmoid( T.dot(th2[2:], nn_hid2) ) ) ; 
nn_predict = nn_predict1 + nn_predict2 ; now I get errore when evauating cost2, Shape mismatch again.

Comment: I have made major edit to question, using your suggestions.

Comment: nn_hid = T.nnet.sigmoid( T.dot(th1[:, 1:], x_sh) + th1[:, 0]) 

I can't say whether this is the only problem in your code but it's a cleaner way to add the bias. You didn't have the : when indexing for the bias, i.e. you used th1[0] which may or may not be the problem. You usually have two theano variables per layer: one for the weights, one for the bias.  But you can do it with one as well.

Comment: In the end with T.concatenate in the function nn_predict worked! The code now runs! There is a new error though...